# remove php file name with extention and replace with value

Tags: .htaccess

I am starting to use htaccess in my project and learned basics such as removing extensions . I am trying to remove a file name in php and replace it with a value being passed in url for eg

```
example.com/eg/check_folder.php?folder=folder-ck
```

to

```
example.com/eg/folder=folder-ck
```

but i am not able achieve this i made the following code. Please guide me with where i am wrong .

```
RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/http://example.com/eg/(\d+)/?$ /http://example.com/eg/check_folder.php?folder=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

First verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not.

Once you make sure it is enabled make sure `mod_rewrite` is also enabled.

Finally use this code in `/eg/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /eg/

RewriteRule ^(folder=.+)$ check_folder.php?$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: the rewrite module is active for sure . I tried your code too but no luck

Comment: Did you do 500 error check for as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: Internal Server Error

Comment: Is this the only rule OR you have some rewrite rules also?

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by using the following code inside my eg folder

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ check_folder.php?folder=$1

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ check_folder.php?folder=$1
```

Comment: This is actually wrong for the example URL you posted. This will not work for `/eg/folder=folder-ck` because of presence of `=` sign.

Comment: it gives me result /eg/folder-ck which is also ok for me. Its working @anubhava thank you again for your help :)

Comment: It worked because you solved a different problem not what was stated in the question. You should edit the question accordingly.